# Install third party application in jailbreaked iphone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Hi i have recently jailbreaked my iphone 2G( 3.1.3).But now i need to install my app into the iphone for testing.I already initiated the process of Apple developer program but it will take a while ,so meanwhile i want to test my application in jaibreaked phone .So anyone could help me how to install third party applications in this iphone.

How many ways are there to do so ,i googled and found submitting to cydia is one way of doing that,but my doubt is that secure way?

Is there any restriction from apple side that it rejects the applications that are already submitted to cydia.

Please help me in clarifying my doubts and installing my application in iphone.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is wait for the developer account to be active. You can then create certificates to run the app on your device. The approval process is very vast so it won't take long to get access to your developer account.

What you can try is to compile the app for the simulator, because you need the certificate to compile for final versions, and then install the app via itunes. You need installous installed on your iPhone, which you can add via Cydia (add source http://cydia[dot]hackulo[dot]us) and this will also install appsync which makes installing apps via iTunes possible.

Hope this is the answer you where looking for..

Comment: Thanks for your response.Could you please provide me details how to submit to cydia and install my app in iphone